# Who were the first female aikidoka?

Tags: aikido, history

When did the first women start training in Aikido? Who were they and where did they train?
Who was the first female aikidoka to achieve teaching rank?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is said that the first female instructor was Takako Kunigoshi. She was one of the first women to train under Ueshiba Sensei and started in January 1933 at what is now the Hombu Dojo. She trained there with another woman, but I don't know her name. Later she was asked to teach self-defense to other women.

More information can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120102150410/https://www.aikidojournal.com/article?articleID=613) and [here](http://members.aikidojournal.com/public/historical-photo-takako-kunigoshi-aiki-budos-first-female-instructor-by-stanley-pranin/)